# Add new column to a table with a value group by value

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-update, alter-table

I have a Circus table as follow

| circus_id | circus_date | circus_show_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09-12-2020 | 78 |
| 2 | 12-01-2021 | 82 |

and a Ticket table as follow

| ticket_id | circus_id | ticket_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Adult |
| 2 | 1 | Student |
| 3 | 1 | Children |
| 4 | 2 | Adult |
| 5 | 2 | Children |
| 6 | 2 | Adult |

and i want to alter the circus table by adding a new column called ticket_sold and the value should be as follow

| circus_id | circus_date | circus_show_price | ticket_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09-12-2020 | 78 | 3 |
| 2 | 12-01-2021 | 82 | 3 |

this is what I have tried

```
 alter table circus add ticket_sold numeric(3) default 0;
 update circus set ticket_sold = (select count(ticket_id) from ticket group by circus_id);
```

it gives me an error said

```
 single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is not `group by` clause you need because query then returns number of tickets per each circus, but - then you get as many rows as there are `circus_id`s in the `ticket` table. Instead, correlate subquery to the main table:

```
update circus c set 
  c.ticket_sold = (select count(t.ticket_id) 
                   from ticket t
                   where t.circus_id = c.circus_id
                  );
```

Answer (score 2):

In-general, don't, as you will end up with a `ticket_sold` column that rapidly becomes out-of-sync with the `ticket` table.

If you want to have a dynamically updating column then:

#### 1. Use a view.

You can just compute the value whenever you need it:

```sql
CREATE VIEW circus_view (circus_id, circus_date, circus_show_price, tickets_sold) AS
SELECT c.circus_id,
       c.circus_date,
       c.circus_show_price,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket t WHERE t.circus_id = c.circus_id)
FROM   circus c;
```

#### 2. Use a trigger.

If you must persist the number of tickets in the `circus` table then:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Circus ADD tickets_sold NUMBER;

CREATE TRIGGER circus_tickets
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Ticket
BEGIN
  UPDATE Circus c
  SET tickets_sold = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket t WHERE t.circus_id = c.circus_id);
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-ppOGvmc)